# How to initialice a variable with the first instance of an array that comes from a server

Tags: angular, typescript

[image of the problem and the seeked result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VGwpu.png)

Here you can see the first component, which gets data from the server, that I couldn't set the selected panel to be activated. The second component, which still gets the data from a mock list, is the visual result i'm after (i.e. having the array[0] to be assingned to the selectedSomething variable).

I have a service for retrieving the data from a mock server and a component that displays it.

Service code:

```
export class ExperienceService {
  private experiencesUrl = 'http://localhost:5000/experiences';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getExperiences(): Observable<Experience[]> {
    return this.http.get<Experience[]>(this.experiencesUrl);
  }
}
```

Component code:

```
export class ExperienceComponent implements OnInit {
  experiences: Experience[] = [];
  selectedExperience: Experience = this.experiences[0];

  constructor(private experienceService: ExperienceService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getExperiences();
  }

  getExperiences() {
    this.experienceService
      .getExperiences()
      .subscribe((experiences) => (this.experiences = experiences));
  }

  onSelect(experience: Experience): void {
    this.selectedExperience = experience;
  }
}
```

So, how do I make the component variable "selectedExperience" to be initialiced with experiences[0]?

(to be clear, the rest of the code is working, when I click the buttons on the left the onSelect function works and each panel appears, but I want the one on the top to be selected from the start)

Comment: How about set the `selectedExperience ` variable in your `subscribe` body of your service call? Because now you set the `[0]` of an empty array immediately after your component is loaded. Moreover, a better solution could be call the service in a resolver (https://angular.io/api/router/Resolve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about initialising it in the `subscribe()` callback?

```
this.experienceService
  .getExperiences()
  .subscribe((experiences) => {
    this.experiences = experiences
    this.selectedExperience = experiences[0]
  });
```

Comment: I just need to mention that it is important to check the response and the response length before accessing it experiences[0].